# Plotting equality and inequality plot together

Tags: plotting

I have two variable {x,y} where three conditions are there

```
x^2 / y = 4.76*10^-11;
x / y < 4.534*10^-3;
```

x runs `{x, 2.8*10^-11, 4.85*10^-11},`

y runs  `{y, 2.2*10^-8, 2.5*10^-8}`

I want to find the allowed region `{x, y}`

Comment: `Reduce[x^2/y == 4.76*10^-11 && x/y < 4.534*10^-3]`

Comment: Are you sure those are the functions?
`RegionPlot[
 x/y < 4.534*10^-3, {x, 2.8*10^-11, 4.85*10^-11}, {y, 2.2*10^-8, 
  2.5*10^-8}]` is all full.
`ContourPlot[
 x^2/y == 4.76*10^-11, {x, 2.8*10^-11, 4.85*10^-11}, {y, 2.2*10^-8, 
  2.5*10^-8}]` is all empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Reduce[x^2/y == 476*^-13 && x/y < 4534*^-6]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[2500000000000 x^2/119, {x, -10^-n, 0},
   PlotStyle -> Blue],
  Plot[2500000000000 x^2/119, {x, 119/11335000000, 10^-n},
   PlotStyle -> Red],
  PlotRange -> {{-10^-n, 10^-n}, Automatic}],
 {{n, 7}, Range[4, 8], ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]